# Changing out one or more pieces of a url in Python 3

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pattern-matching

I am building image links in Python 3.  I am getting a basic starter link and I am being given one or more elements that need to be switched out based on a pattern that is tied to that original link to create my new image link.  I am being given the links and the elements and I can tie each link type to a pattern that I can store in the database.  What I am looking for is the best way to create the pattern to switch out the data.

For Example:
The first link I get is: https://testurl.com/images/320/new.jpg
I am given a value of 450 and the pattern dictates that the 450 should be swapped out with the 320 to make a new link of: https://testurl.com/images/450/new.jpg.

The second link I get is http://newurl.com/stuff/image.jpg?resize=100
I am given a value of 200 and the pattern dictates that the 200 needs to replace the 100 to make a new link of http://newurl.com/stuff/image.jpg.resize=200

The third link I get is http://anotherlink.com/01/02/2016/today/newfolder/image.jpg  I am given a string of 02/15/2016 that needs to be swapped out with the 01/02/2016 and a string of oldfolder that needs to be swapped out with the newfolder giving me a link of http://anotherlink.com/02/15/2016/today/oldfolder/image.jpg

Is there a way to store patterns that could handle all 3 different scenarios?  Again, I can have a unique pattern for each, I just would need the same code to be able to execute all 3 patterns successfully.

I was thinking I could do this with a regex and I have done validation with it in the past but I'm not sure if there is a way to actually change out parts of strings based on a pattern instead of just matching.

My other thought was to create a template and do a find and replace loop until all the replace elements have been swapped out but that seems messy.  Any suggestions?

Comment: `"https://testurl.com/images/320/new.jpg".replace("320", "450")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got this code which should do what you ask, I haven't tested it yet, but add a comment if it doesn't work, or if it doesn't do what you want:

```
url=""         #URL to use
replace=""  #string to replace original with
if "resize=" in url:
    for i in range(len(url)):
        try:
            int(url[-1:])
        except Exception:
            break
        else:
            url=url[:-1]
    url+=str(replace)
elif [e for e in range(len(url)) if url[e:][:(e+10)].replace("/","").isalpha()==False]:
    for e in range(len(url)):
        if url[:(e+10)][e:].replace("/","").isdigit()==True:
            if url[e:][:1]!="/":
                url=url[:e]+replace+url[(e+10):]
                url=url.replace("newfolder","oldfolder")
                break
else:
    url1=url.split("/")
    url1[len(url1)-2]=replace
    url=""
    for i in url1:
        url+=i+"/"
print(url)
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

I have now tested the code, and fixed the bugs, and it seems to work fine, but still add a comment if it doesn't work.

Comment: Great.  Thank you.  I'll give this a try today and let you know.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: I used what you gave me as a base and did a bit more automation specific to the variables getting passed in but in the end this was extremely helpful.  Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help.